# Can I take an electric fly swatter on board?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security

I have a 1500V electric fly swatter - the type you can get at £1 stores and on Amazon - it looks like a small tennis racket but it has 2AA batteries to kill insects. I would like to take it with me from the UK to France. My guess would be that it loosely falls under "electro shock weapons" and can't be taken on board. I say loosely because I doubt something with 2AA batteries could do serious damage to a person.

Yes, it sounds stupid. However, every time I go to France I get bitten by mosquitos and this would be a very convenient and satisfying way of dealing with the problem.

I'd be happy to put it in hold luggage and/or take out the batteries.

Comment: The airline is Flybe

Comment: Can you simply find one at a 1 € store in France?

Comment: If I knew I could, I'd be happy with that, but it's a small town and I can't think of anywhere that might sell them.

Comment: I saw that but thought it was a typo since explosives etc. aren't electro shock weapons, and more generally need some idea of whether your typical airport security worker might think - because ultimately that's what matters.

Comment: Apologies, I thought it went without saying that I'd already looked on their website :)

Comment: I have flown with mosquito zapper paddles in my checked baggage frequently between Asia and the US and within US / Canada.  No one much cared.  I, however, wouldn't take one on board in my carry on bag.

Comment: You should mention in the question that you are travelling by aeroplane, because rules are obviously different between aeroplanes, boats, trains, buses, or dinghies.

Comment: *"I doubt something with 2AA batteries could do serious damage to a person"* I could definitely design something that would kill you using the energy from two AA batteries. Two AA batteries contain roughly the muzzle energy from 40 or 50 9mm Parabellum bullets or 10 7.62 x 39mm rifle rounds. It would cost more than £1, though.

Comment: I have never seen any of these in France, so buying another one there is probably not a good solution.

Comment: Violet wands can be taken, or so I'm told, so I'm sure an electronic paddle can as well....oh, heck, wrong exchange.... ;)

Comment: @CGCampbell [... company policy: we have to use the indefinite "a dildo" ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Dwj2m0G7xck#t=1465)

Comment: Did you make it with the zapper through the airport security? I’ve got the same dilemma

Answer (score 2):

Remove the battery from the device and isolate the connectors on each AA battery as a precaution. You should have no trouble, if Customs asks, tell them what it is and let them decide.